# Duality between center of group and its outer automorphism group

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

The wikipedia page says that if G is a group, then Z(G) and Out(G) are dual, in the sense that Z(G) is a kernel of a certain homomorphism from G to Aut(G), and Out(G) is its cokernel (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_automorphism_group)
This gives rise to the following commutative diagram:
[image]

Where the 0's are 0 morphisms, i is a natural inclusion,  $\pi$ is the projection that sends every element of Aut(G) to its left coset, and f is the homomorphism that sends every element g in G to the conjugation by g.
By looking at this diagram, it's posssible to see that the notion of duality arises quite a bit. For example, $\pi$ is a surjection, and i is an injection. The 0 morphism in the upper part goes from some place to the target of f, while the zero on the downwards part goes from the source of f to some place. There are several other simetries like these in this diagram, that all hint to the notion of duality.

My problem, however, is that even with all of that information, it isn't clear to me what it's supposed to mean for them to be dual to each other.
From a categorical view, one could argue that if we look at this diagram in the opposite category of groups (revert the orientation of the arrows), then Z(G) would be the cokernel of the dual of f, and Out(G) would be the kernel of that same morphism. However, that doesn't seem to actually have any intrinsic meaning, since the dual of f doesn't have to be a function (and I imagine it probably isn't one).

So here's my question:

Is there anything meaningful that can be taken from the statement that these two objects are dual? If so, what is it?

Comment: Please add the wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_automorphism_group). Then we see the details, which you have left out (what the "certain" homomorphism is precisely etc.). "Is there anything meaningful that can be taken from it?" Yes,  the facts that $Out(G)=Aut(G)/Inn(G)$ and $G/Z(G)={\rm Inn}(G)$.

Comment: The homomorphism f is a very specific one, that does always exist. I just left it out initially but it will be added.

Comment: @markvs  $f$ is just the standard homomorphism that maps $g$ to conjugation by $g$, and it certainly always exists.  The cokernel is the quotient of the codomain by the image, and there is no requirement for it to be a subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why is the image a normal subgroup?

Comment: @markvs given a combination of group elements $g_i$ and a variable $x$ using only the group operation and group inverse, the result of applying an automorphism $f$ after replacing the variable with $f^{-1}(x)$ is the same expression with each $g_i$ replaced with $f(g_i)$. In particular, a conjugation expression $gxg^{-1}$ becomes $f(g)xf(g)^{-1}$, so the subgroup of inner automorphisms is normal.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov: In this particular example, the image is normal of course. I was asking about an arbitrary $f$. I guess not every homomorphism has a co-kernel.

Comment: @markvs: The cokernel is defined via the corresponding universal property. It is the coequalizer of the morphism and the zero map. For groups, it is the quotient modulo the normal closure of the image.